# E-mail regex without one specific domain

Tags: regex, match

It's possible create e-mail regex with matching this rules:

[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}

but without domain "google.com"

Comment: Add `(?!google\.com$)` after `@`

Comment: perfect Wiktor, thanks.